# How to Convert the following tf 1.x code to tf 2.0 (With minimal changes to existing code)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am migrating code from `tensorflow 1.x` to `tensorflow-2.0`. I have used the conversion script provided in `tensorflow-2.0` and it was good. However the script cannot convert `tf.contrib` module's code. I want to make the following code `tensorflow-2.0` compatible.

```
def dropout(input_tensor, dropout_prob):
  """Perform dropout.

  Args:
    input_tensor: float Tensor.
    dropout_prob: Python float. The probability of dropping out a value (NOT of
      *keeping* a dimension as in `tf.nn.dropout`).

  Returns:
    A version of `input_tensor` with dropout applied.
  """
  if dropout_prob is None or dropout_prob == 0.0:
    return input_tensor

  output = tf.nn.dropout(input_tensor, 1 - (1.0 - dropout_prob))
  return output

def layer_norm(input_tensor, name=None):
  """Run layer normalization on the last dimension of the tensor."""
  return tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(
      inputs=input_tensor, begin_norm_axis=-1, begin_params_axis=-1, scope=name)


def layer_norm_and_dropout(input_tensor, dropout_prob, name=None):
  """Runs layer normalization followed by dropout."""
  output_tensor = layer_norm(input_tensor, name)
  output_tensor = dropout(output_tensor, dropout_prob)
  return output_tensor
```

Error I Encounter:

1) Using Member tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm in deprecated module tf.contrib.layer_norm

My search on the internet found me this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26854)

However it is still not clear how to migrate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use `tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()`? See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization).

Comment: I did see that API, But observe the stark differences between inputs to both of them.One is old-school tensorflow, other is high-level keras.My question is how to convert the above code with minimal changes to other code in project.

Comment: You can implement a custom layer norm function like [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-spatial-batch-instance-layer-normalization-in-tensorflow-manual-back-prop-in-tf-77faa8d2c362).

Comment: Would try that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For layer normalization, migrating to Keras layers works for me and gives me similar fine-tuned model performance.

```
def dropout(input_tensor, dropout_prob):
    """Perform dropout.

    Args:
      input_tensor: float Tensor.
      dropout_prob: Python float. The probability of dropping out a value (NOT of
        *keeping* a dimension as in `tf.nn.dropout`).

    Returns:
      A version of `input_tensor` with dropout applied.
    """
    if dropout_prob is None or dropout_prob == 0.0:
        return input_tensor

    output = tf.nn.dropout(input_tensor, dropout_prob) # tf 2.10
    return output


def layer_norm(input_tensor, name=None):
    """Run layer normalization on the last dimension of the tensor."""
    input_layer_norm = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(
        axis=-1, name=name, epsilon=1e-12, dtype=tf.float32)
    return input_layer_norm(input_tensor)


def layer_norm_and_dropout(input_tensor, dropout_prob, name=None):
    """Runs layer normalization followed by dropout."""
    output_tensor = layer_norm(input_tensor, name)
    # output_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_prob)(output_tensor)
    output_tensor = dropout(output_tensor, dropout_prob)
    return output_tensor
```

The caveat is that `tf.nn.dropout`  takes **dropout probability** instead of **keep probability** as in TF1.x versions, otherwise you are dropping out 90% layer outputs for the default 10% BERT drop rate. You may refer to further details in the official transformer encoder here.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/nlp/modeling/networks/transformer_encoder.py